# Google Cross-client Identity

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I have been digging everywhere to implement [Cross-client Identity](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth) using Google Identity Platform on IOS but was not able to find a solid answer on how to proceed. This StackOverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369492/is-google-cross-client-auth-possible-with-ios-and-if-so-how) suggest that I use GPPSignIn to give authorization to my server and let my server take over from there. Unfortunately the scopes provided by GPPSignIn does not give me access to Google Calendar. The implementation is straight forward on Android was able to wire it without any problems.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve.

1 - On the IOS app, users signs in using their Google credential (Request Google for one time authorization code.

2 - Send the one time authorization code to my back-end server via https and allow my back-end to get offline access and refresh token on behalf of my app.

The implementation is straight forward on Android was able to wire it without any problem using this guid [Cross-client Identity](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Okay I answered my own question. I was able to resolve it by using https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/offline-access

Comment: Where did you get that `server auth code`?