# Getting Google one-time authorization code

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, google-authentication, google-cloud-platform

I am having trouble getting a one-time authorization code from Google.  I am attempting to get  the authorization code from an Android client so that I can send it to my Rails backend (web client).

In my Google Cloud Developer Console I have an application with two Client IDs:

1. Client ID for web application (for my rails backend)
2. Client ID for Android application (for my android client).  The SHA1 used is from ~/.android/debug.keystore

Suppose the Web Application Client ID is `12345.apps.googleusercontent.com`

Suppose the Android Client ID is `67890.apps.googleusercontent.com`

**This is some of my code:**

```
private final static String WEB_CLIENT_ID = "12345.apps.googleusercontent.com";
private final static String GOOGLE_CALENDAR_API_SCOPE = "audience:server:client_id:" + WEB_CLIENT_ID;

private void getAndUseAuthToken(final String email) {
        AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... emails) {
                try {
                    return GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(AddExternalCalendarsActivity.this, emails[0], GOOGLE_CALENDAR_API_SCOPE);
                } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
                    startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), IntentConstants.REQUEST_GOOGLE_AUTHORIZATION);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String authToken) {
                if (authToken != null) {
                    saveTokenAndGetCalendars(email, authToken);
                }
            }
        };

        String[] emails = new String[1];
        emails[0] = email;
        task.execute(emails);
    }
```

**Some additional notes**

- I am hitting the GoogleAuthException and receiving "Unknown" as the message detail
- I'm unable to add additional members in the permissions of the Google Cloud Console for this project - when adding a new member a popup appears with "Server Error.  Whoops! Our bad.".  I have sent feedback to Google twice.
- I'm referring to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/CrossClientAuth).  Notice the quote below. By "fixed", are they saying that I do not need to prepend **audience:server:client_id** in my GOOGLE_CALENDAR_API_SCOPE variable? I've tried both with and without and still getting the same GoogleAuthException.

> In this situation, the Android app can call the
>   GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() method on behalf of any of the Google
>   accounts on the device, and with a scope argument value of
>   audience:server:client_id:9414861317621.apps.googleusercontent.com.
>   The prefix audience:server:client_id: is fixed, and the rest of the
>   scope string is the client ID of the web component.

- If I use this scope, I can authenticate with google from device.  However, the documentation I've read suggests that I need to use the server web client id (which is in the same google console project as the android client id) in the scope in order for the server to hit the google api on behalf of the user who authorized it on the android client:

  `private final static String GOOGLE_CALENDAR_API_SCOPE = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar";`

**UPDATE 1**

I originally added in answer:
*The reason for my first problem - I am hitting the GoogleAuthException and receiving "Unknown" as the message detail - was a mistake I made when adding the android client id in the cloud console. The SHA1 was correct but I did not type the package name correctly. I used com.company.app when my android package is actually com.company.android.app.
The code in the original question works fine. Just make sure you have all the necessary clients in your Google Cloud Console project.*

But another problem still exists.  When I send the one-time authorization token returned from *GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()* to the Rails backend, and then try to exchange it for an access_token and refresh_token, I get the follow:

```
Signet::AuthorizationError:
  Authorization failed.  Server message:
  {
      "error" : "invalid_grant"
  }
```

This [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline) and several SO posts suggests that I need to set `access_type=offline`.  But I think that is when you are requesting the one-time authorization code and offline access from a Web Server.  I'm trying to request the one-time authorization code from an Android client and send it to the web server.

Is this possible with **GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()**?

**UPDATE 2**

Google Plus login must be in the scope even if you're only trying to access the calendar:

```
private final static String GOOGLE_CALENDAR_API_SCOPE = "oauth2:server:client_id:" + WEB_CLIENT_ID + ":api_scope:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar";
```

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361054/getting-google-oauth-authorization-token-from-android-return-with-invalid-scope) was helpful.  Also, [Google's Cross Client identity documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/CrossClientAuth) does state:

> [Note: This policy in being rolled out gradually. For the moment, when access tokens are involved, it only applies when the requested scopes include https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login.]

I'll summarize in an answer if the token exchange works on Rails backend.

Comment: How do you get an offline authorization code (access_type=offline) with GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()? Did you manage to do that?

Comment: @grebulon Yes, I was able to get a one-time authorization code with GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() after completing the things in the accepted answer. I sent that one-time authorization code to to our backend server, which used it to get a google api token.

Comment: I almost get it to work... In my flow, I keep getting UserRecoverableAuthException(NeedPermission) for the offline permission. Starting the received intent and calling getToken, launches the add permission dialog again for the offline permission, and so on in an infinite loop.

Comment: You should start a new question and post some code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things solved this for me:

1. Make sure the Android and Web Client IDs are setup in correctly in the same Google Cloud Console project.
2. Use the correct scope.  Plus login is required even if you're only accessing the calendar api:

   // the id of the web server that is exchanging the auth code for access and refresh tokens

   private final static String WEB_CLIENT_ID = "12345.apps.googleusercontent.com";
   private final static String GOOGLE_CALENDAR_API_SCOPE = "oauth2:server:client_id:" + WEB_CLIENT_ID + ":api_scope:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar";

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've done:

```
final String authToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getTokenWithNotification (this.context, account.name, "oauth2:" + AuthUtils.profileScope, new Bundle (),
                Contract.authority, new Bundle ());
```

But you plain getToken should work the same for a foreground activity.

Take this token, send it to the server in an a way you can use it like an HTTP header (over HTTPS). As long as the server scope is a subset of the scope used to acquire the token, you shouldn't have a problem. The server uses the server id and the android client uses the android client id.

You should set your scope to either:

```
oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
```

or

```
oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly
```

See https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth

Edit: OK I see what you are trying to do. The scope value is a space separated list so you would likely need to append audience:server:client_id: to your scope like:

```
"oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar audience:server:client_id:12345-your-web-component-client-id"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The scope above returns a GoogleAuthException - "INVALID_SCOPE".  I think this is because Google only requires authorization once from clients in the same project.  I *think* that's what they're saying [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/CrossClientAuth)